# Cookie is sent, but not stored when deployed

Tags: express, authentication, heroku, vercel, httpcookie

**I'm having issues with cookies in a MERN app hosted to Vercel (Front-end) and Heroku (Back-end).**

Everything is working fine in localhost, but when deployed i'm having issues storing cookies. Set-Cookie is sent with the sign in request, and the request itself looks fine. **I get no errors.**

After being signed in, authenticated routes return what I expect for each user, so the cookie seems to be accessible to the back-end even tho the cookie is not stored on the front-end under storage, which I assume is a security issue. This is *not* the case in Safari, in Safari the cookies are gone after login, so the user is logged out again.

<strike>The only route that does not work is signing *out*. On sign out I clear the token cookie, but it is trying to delete something that *technically* isn't there, still no errors.</strike> **UPDATE: Clearing cookie works!** I wasn't sending any data back with the sign out, so the front-end thought it was unresponsive, adding a `.send({ message: 'Sign Out Successful' })` solved that issue. However, still no cookie visible in the front-end storage.

For **CORS** settings I have the origin set to the front-end url, and credentials set to true. While on the front-end I have `withCredentials: true` set on every request.

When deployed, the cookie is using `sameSite: none`, and `secure: true`.

Below are the sign in and sign out routes.

**Sign in route on back-end**

```
import type Route from '../../types/Route'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import env from '../../env/env'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

import User from '../../models/User'
import validateSignIn from '../../utils/validation/signIn'

const route: Route = {
  method: 'post',
  execute: async (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body.user

    try {
      const { errors, valid } = validateSignIn(username, password)
      if (!valid) return res.status(401).send({ errors })
      
      const user = await User.findOne({ username })
      if (!user) return res.status(404).send({ errors: { username: 'User not found' }})

      const correctPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
      if (!correctPassword) return res.status(401).send({ errors: { password: 'Wrong password' } })

      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, env.SECRET, { expiresIn: "1hr" })
      return res.status(200).cookie('token', token, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 604800000),
        secure: env.ENVIRONMENT === 'LIVE',
        sameSite: env.ENVIRONMENT === 'LIVE' ? 'none' : 'lax',
        httpOnly: true
      }).send(user)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('@sign/in', error)
      return res.sendStatus(500)
    }
  }
}

export default route
```

**Sign out route on back-end:**

```
import type Route from '../../types/Route'
import authorization from '../../middlewares/http'
import env from '../../env/env'

const route: Route = {
  method: 'get',
  authorization,
  execute: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      return res.clearCookie('token').sendStatus(200)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('@sign/out', error)
      return res.status(500)
    }
  }
}

export default route
```

Comment: _"The cookie seems to be stored on the back-end url, rather than the front-end"_ - can you please clarify, what you actually mean by that?

Comment: @CBroe, sorry, I just removed this section as that stopped happening! But what I meant at the time is that the cookies were saved under the application tab in dev tools on the back-end, not the front-end as expected.

Comment: The cookie is set by your backend code so it is saved in the browser using the backend's domain. Your frontend shouldn't care about this cookie, as it is the backend that needs it.

Comment: Can you specify what do you expect currently to happen and what is happening? From what you described in the question it looks like a perfectly fine behaviour of an app.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski what I expect is for my cookie to be stored inside the Application => Storage => Cookies tab on the front-end, but the tab is empty. This is where I'm used to seeing cookies stored in my apps.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to see cookies from your backend assigned to the frontend app. These cookies are set and required by your backend, the frontend does not need them, and can't use them. If you really want to see them assigned to frontend then you have to ensure that both backend and frontend are using the same domain (parent domain is enough).

Answer (score 0):

The [.clearCookie()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie) doc says

> Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to res.cookie(), excluding expires and maxAge.

So, try making your clear operation match your set operation, something like this.

```js
res
  .clearCookie('token', token, {
        secure: env.ENVIRONMENT === 'LIVE',
        sameSite: env.ENVIRONMENT === 'LIVE' ? 'none' : 'lax',
        httpOnly: true })
  .sendStatus(200)
```

Comment: I just made these changes, and it sadly had no effect.